# [__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 1} out of bounds; string length 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, substring

We have a method that computes a substring from a string with the help of the `substringWithRange` method. The `startIndex` is always 0 and the length of the substring never exceeds the string length. Even then, we are seeing `[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]` exceptions in production. Below is the code block computing the substring.

```
- (void)setItemTitle:(NSString *)title color:(UIColor *)color {
    self.titleLabel.text = title;

    NSUInteger placeholderTextLength = MIN(2,title.length);
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, placeholderTextLength);
    self.placeholderLabel.text = [[title substringWithRange:range] capitalizedString];
    self.placeholderLabel.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

This method is being called from the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath` tableView delegate method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Item *item = [self itemForIndexPath:indexPath];

    COSItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.defaultItemCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setItemTitle:item.title color:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

We are really confused about this behavior. Anyone has a clue about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and worked out where the string is coming from?  Until you can reliably reproduce the crash you probably won't solve the problem.

Comment: This is a production bug and none of us have been able to reproduce it which is making it even more difficult.

Comment: Is it possible in production the title is an empty string?  Where is the title data coming from?  Would you be able to post some part of the cellForRowAtIndexPath where you call setItemTitle

Comment: Even if the string was empty it wouldn't crash as `placeholderTextLength` would be 0. The title data comes from our backend. Updated the original question with parts of of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method